# Normalize binary features for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, normalization, binary-data

I am applying logistic regression and I am using a mixture of continuous and binary features. 
My question would be how do you go about binary features when trying to normalize.
I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think you really need to do any normalization. Clearly your means and variances are already in the same magnitudes.

Comment: Why do you want to normalize your data in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Normalization means that you put your data in a particular range, often $0$ to $1$. If you have coded your binary variable with $0$ and $1$, you already have this property and do not need to do anything. If you use a different type of coding of your binary variable, [such as $\pm 1$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/609727/247274), then the usual $\dfrac{x_i - \min(x)}{\max(x) - \min(x)}$ should work.

If you have not coded your categories with numbers, your software does it under the hood, and the documentation should say how.